# Firebase Messaging Dependencies Issue

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I've been trying to add Firebase cloud messaging to my app but can't get pass this issue. Whenever I include firebase messaging in my `android>app>build.gradle`, my app launches but the immediately closes then just hangs on *"Installing build\app\outputs\apk\app.apk"*:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.1.6'
```

android>app>build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
    //implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.1.6' 
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

android>build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
    }
```

I'm not sure whether this is a versioning issue?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding to release notes

> The Firebase Android library firebase-core is no longer needed. This
>   SDK included the Firebase SDK for Google Analytics.

https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android

Also, use google play service plugin version 4.3.3

```
classpath com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3
```

Comment: I removed firebase-core dependency and altered plugin to version 4.3.3 as suggested but it still just hangs at "Installing build\app\outputs\apk\app.apk". Whenever I remove firebase-messaging dependency, it runs perfect.

Comment: Just hangs, never completes the "Installing" phase. What I do notice on my phone is the app being launched and then immediately closed. Not sure if that has any relevance to the issue.

Comment: Check logcat and send crash log

Answer (score 0):

Your could use bom(Bill Of Material) of firebase like this:

```
implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:27.1.0')

implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging'
```

then to import (in your activity):

```
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessaging;
.
.

@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) {

      FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("all").addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
            Log.e("my_tag", "successfully register in topic");
          }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
           @Override
           public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            Log.e("my_tag", e.getMessage());
           }
    });
}
```